# Scanning big binary with Erlang

Tags: file-io, erlang, pattern-matching, binaryfiles

I like to scan larger(>500M) binary files for structs/patterns. I am new to the language an hope that someone can give me start. Actually the files are a database containing Segments. A Segment starts with a fixed sized header followed by a fixed sized optional part followed by the payload/data part of variable lenght. For a first test i just like to log the number of segments in the file. I googled already for some tutorial but found nothing which helped. I need a hint or a tutorial which is not too far from my use case to get started.

Greets
Stefan

Comment: It would also help with an example of the binary you are trying to parse and what the end result should look like.

Answer (score 4):

you need to learn about [**Bit Syntax**](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#bit-syntax) and **[Binary Comprehensions](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#binary-comprehensions)**. More useful links to follow: http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.6/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html, and http://goto0.cubelogic.org/a/90.
You will also need to learn how to process files, reading from files (line-by-line, chunk-by-chunk, at given positions in a file, e.t.c.), writing to files in several ways. The file processing functions are explained [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html)
 You can also choose to look at the source code of large file processing libraries within the erlang packages e.g. [Disk Log](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/disk_log.html), [Dets](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html) and [mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html). These libraries heavily read and write into files and their source code is open for you to see.
 I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is a synthesized sample problem: I have a binary file (**test.txt**) that I want to parse. I want to find all the binary patterns of `<<$a, $b, $c>>` in the file.

The content of "**test.txt**":

```
I arbitrarily decide to choose the string "abc" as my target string for my test. I want to find all the abc's in my testing file.
```

A sample program (**lab.erl**):

```
-module(lab).
-compile(export_all).

find(BinPattern, InputFile) ->
    BinPatternLength = length(binary_to_list(BinPattern)),
    {ok, S} = file:open(InputFile, [read, binary, raw]),
    loop(S, BinPattern, 0, BinPatternLength, 0),
    file:close(S),
    io:format("Done!~n", []).

loop(S, BinPattern, StartPos, Length, Acc) ->
    case file:pread(S, StartPos, Length) of
    {ok, Bin} ->
        case Bin of
        BinPattern ->
            io:format("Found one at position: ~p.~n", [StartPos]),
            loop(S, BinPattern, StartPos + 1, Length, Acc + 1);
        _ ->
            loop(S, BinPattern, StartPos + 1, Length, Acc)
        end;
    eof ->
        io:format("I've proudly found ~p matches:)~n", [Acc])
    end.
```

Run it:

```
1> c(lab).
{ok,lab}
2> lab:find(<<"abc">>, "./test.txt").     
Found one at position: 43.
Found one at position: 103.
I've proudly found 2 matches:)
Done!
ok
```

Note that the code above is not very efficient (the scanning process shifts one byte at a time) and it is sequential (not utilizing all the "cores" on your computer). It is meant only to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

When your data fits into memory, best thing what you can to do is read data in whole using `file:read_file/1`. If you can't use file in `raw` mode. Then you can parse data using bit_syntax. If you write it in right manner you can achieve parsing speed in tens of MB/s when parsing module is compile using HiPE. Exact techniques of parsing depends on exact segment data format and how robust/accurate result you are looking for. For parallel parsing you can inspire by [Tim Bray's Wide Finder project](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/09/20/Wide-Finder).